# SDL_Texture becoming NULL on itself

Tags: c++, pointers, textures, sdl

I'm having a problem with SDL.
I have a CLASS_Text class for text objects, which holds SDL_Texture * for the rendered text. It uses a external CLASS_Font to render the texture to it via SDL_Texture*&. Works fine when I try to use the texture inside the constructor but when I try to render the text where it should it doesn't work as _Texture has for some reason become NULL and I can't wrap my head around it. It isn't a local variable and it is loaded to the private pointer in CLASS_Text in constructor.
I use similiar desing in other texture's class and it seems to work fine there so I can't figure out why it doesn't in this case.

When I render the text texture after declaring the object like this

```
text.Render();
SDL_RenderPresent( getRenderer() );
SDL_Delay( 2000 );
```

It works! This is outside the constructor. But when I do the exactly same thing later in Window's render function it doesn't work, does the RenderCopy somehow make the texture pointer NULL?

Here's the Text class' render function:

```
//Render the texture to its position on the screen
void CLASS_Text::Render(){
if( _isLoaded && (_Texture != NULL) ){
    SDL_Rect dest_rec{ _X, _Y, _Width, _Height };
    SDL_RenderCopy( getRenderer(), _Texture, NULL, &dest_rec );
} else{
    std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Error rendering text object, it is not loaded properly! \n";
}
}
```

CLASS_Text

class CLASS_Text{

```
//Declare font classes friends so they can render to texture
friend class CLASS_Font;
friend class CLASS_BitMapFont;

//Hardware texture
SDL_Texture * _Texture;

//Text
std::string _Text;

//Rendering type
TEXT_RENDERTYPE _RenderType;

//Pointer to truetype font
CLASS_Font * _Font;
//Pointer to bitmap font
CLASS_BitMapFont * _BMFont;

//If flag is true then font is truetype, otherwise bitmap font
bool _isTrueType;

//Text color
SDL_Color _Color;
//Text backgroundcolor
SDL_Color _BackgroundColor;

//Flag indicates whether text has a solid color background
bool _hasBackGround;

//Coordinates
int _X;
int _Y;
//Size in pixels
int _Width;
int _Height;

//Misc variables
int _WordCount;
int _Length;

//Is the texture loaded
bool _isLoaded;

public:

//Constructor and destructor
CLASS_Text( std::string text, int x, int y, Abstract_Font * font, SDL_Color textcolor = {255,255,255}, std::string name = "Unnamed", TEXT_RENDERTYPE rendertype = TEXT_SOLID,
            bool background = false, SDL_Color bgcolor = {0,0,0} );
CLASS_Text( std::string text, int x, int y, STYLE_Text& style, std::string name = "Unnamed" ); //Using text style
~CLASS_Text();
//Free texture
void Free();

void ChangePosition( int x, int y );
void ChangeText( std::string newtext, bool rerender = false );
void ChangeFont( Abstract_Font * newfont );
void ChangeFont( std::string fontname );
void ChangeRenderType( TEXT_RENDERTYPE type );

//Sets the text color, requires regeneration
void SetColor( Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue );
//Set text bg on/off
void SetBackground( bool on_off );
void SetBgColor( Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue );

//Delete the previous texture and render new
void Load();

//Render the texture
void Render();
//Another render, which ignores the text objects'
//coordinates and renders to given location instead
void Render( int x, int y );

};
```

---

This is the Load() function

```
//Delete the previous texture and render new
void CLASS_Text::Load(){

//Free previous texture
Free();

//False until rendered succesfully
_isLoaded = false;

//Set texture to NULL
_Texture = NULL;

if( _isTrueType ){
    //If it is truetype the rendering happens with CLASS_Font's functions
    switch( _RenderType ){
    case TEXT_SOLID:
        if( TextDebug )
            std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Rendering SOLID TrueType text \n";
        _Font->RenderText( _Texture, _Text, _Color, _Width, _Height, TEXT_SOLID );
        _isLoaded = true;
        break;
    case TEXT_SHADED:
        if( TextDebug )
            std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Rendering SHADED TrueType text \n";
        _Font->RenderText_Shaded( _Texture, _Text, _Color, _BackgroundColor, _Width, _Height );
        _isLoaded = true;
        break;
    case TEXT_BLENDED:
        if( TextDebug )
            std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Rendering BLENDED TrueType text \n";
        _Font->RenderText_Blended( _Texture, _Text, _Color, _Width, _Height );
        _isLoaded = true;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Invalid rendering type " << _RenderType << "\n";
    }
} else{
    if( TextDebug )
        std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Rendering bitmap text \n";
    //Else it's bitmap and is rendered as such
}

if( TextDebug )
    std::cout << DEBUG_TEXT << "Rendered text object \n";

}
```

And this is Font's text rendering function

```
void CLASS_Font::RenderText( SDL_Texture*& texture, std::string text, SDL_Color textcolor, int& width, int& height, TEXT_RENDERTYPE type, SDL_Color bgcolor ){
//If there's a texture already remove it
if( texture != NULL ){
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texture );
}
SDL_Surface * textSurface;
//Render text surface
switch( type ){
case TEXT_SOLID: //SOLID
    textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( _Font, text.c_str(), textcolor );
    break;
case TEXT_SHADED: //SHADED
    textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded( _Font, text.c_str(), textcolor, bgcolor );
    break;
case TEXT_BLENDED: //BLENDED
    textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended( _Font, text.c_str(), textcolor );
    break;
default:
    std::cout << DEBUG_FONT << "Error! Invalid rendering type \n";
    return;
}

//Check if the rendering was successfull
if( textSurface == NULL )
{
    std::cout << DEBUG_FONT << "Rendering text surface failed \n";
    return;
}

//Convert surface to display format
SDL_Surface * formattedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat( textSurface, Current_Window->getWindowPixelFormat(), NULL);

//Check the converted surface
if( formattedSurface == NULL )
{
    std::cout << DEBUG_FONT << "Converting text surface failed \n";
    return;
}

//Create texture from surface pixels
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( getRenderer(), formattedSurface );
if( texture == NULL )
{
    std::cout << DEBUG_FONT << "Error creating text texture \n";
}
else
{
    width = textSurface->w;
    height = textSurface->h;

    if( TextDebug )
        std::cout << DEBUG_FONT << "Text surface successfully rendered and converted to texture \n";
}

//Free the temporary surfaces
SDL_FreeSurface( textSurface );
SDL_FreeSurface( formattedSurface );

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should post the c'tor of CLASS_Text as it's vital to understand why render doesn't work from there.

however, perhaps render function uses some class members that aren't being initialized at the exact location in c'tor where you call this function(such as the coordinates _X and _Y).

try calling render at the end of the c'tor.

Comment: Okay o.O I put it to output values in Render(), and for some reason x is 1, y changes between 0 and 1 and width increases constantly, i have absolutely no idea what could cause this. I don't edit them at any point..